# <DOCtype > is changing to quirks

Tags: html, internet-explorer, jsp, doctype

I have defined the `<DOCTYPE>` in jsp page

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

but when opening the page in  IE8 it's getting changed to

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
```

which is causing menus issue, hover is not working.
Could you tell em why `<DOCTYPE>` is getting changed.

Comment: I'm about 88% sure IE8 does not support XHTML at all.  So even if it didn't change the doctype, you might still be in quirks mode.

Comment: when i tried to create a small html page with

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> it's working fine but in site it's getting changed to <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN"> which is making quirks mode default

Comment: IE doesn't "change DOCTYPEs". Are you sure you aren't looking at a cached version or the wrong URL?

Comment: it's resolved now there were some extra blanks generating before <DOCTYPE> i removed those spaces and it worked. Thanks frnds for your help.